# Regex is not matching in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to match the following pattern using C# and getting no match found

Regex

```
^([[a-z][A-Z]]*):([[a-z][A-Z][0-9],]*)$
```

Sample String

```
Student:Tom,Jerry
```

Whereas the same thing works in ruby(verified it using [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)). Any idea why this is not working in c#?

Code Block

```
public static KeyValuePair<string, IList<string>> Parse(string s)
    {
        var pattern = new Regex(@"(\w*):([\w\d,]*)");
        var matches = pattern.Matches(s);
        if (matches.Count == 2)
        {
            return new KeyValuePair<string, IList<string>>(matches[0].Value, matches[1].Value.Split(','));
        }

        throw new System.FormatException();
    }
```

Comment: Really am not to familiar with c, any chance you need to escape something?

Comment: You are doing ranges wrong, should be: `^([a-zA-Z]*):([a-zA-Z0-9,]*)$`

Comment: [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) is a good tool for this sort of thing: Here's your example [working](http://regexr.com?31kih) and [not working](http://regexr.com?31kik).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing your regex slightly :-

```
([a-zA-Z]*):([a-zA-Z0-9,]*)
```

You could even simplify it a little further if you want all word characters (including underscore), if not then use the one above.

```
(\w*):([\w\d,]*)
```

There's no need to multi-group groupings such as `[[a-z][A-Z]]`

Comment: It works but when I call Matches I am getting only one match whereas I am expecting two match groups

Comment: @KrishnaswamySubramanian are you still using the same Test phrase? I just tried it over at http://regexr.com?31kin and on a C# app and it works perfectly for me :( Using "Student:Tom,Jerry" It shows two groups "Student" and "Tom,Jerry"

Comment: Yes! But still getting only one match
var pattern = new Regex(@"(\w*):([\w\d,]*)");
pattern.matches("Student:Tom,Jerry")

Comment: @KrishnaswamySubramanian would you mind updating your question with he code your using to match and we can check Regex options and such for you?

Comment: @KrishnaswamySubramanian You are getting one match, because the text really contains only one match for your pattern. However, that match should contain multiple *groups* - try examining collection `pattern.Matches("Student:Tom,Jerry")[0].Groups`. With texts like that, it makes more sense to use `Match` method, not `Matches`, which is only useful if you expect your text to contain more matches  of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it even more:

```
^([A-z]*):([\w,]*)$
```

The first group is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z]` and the second to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. If you want the first group to match digits along with characters, you can simply use `\w` everywhere.